# Absolute position top in relative box different between browsers

Tags: html, css, position

I have a sub navigation which is placed in two different places on different browsers, and I'm unsure why. I do realise that using margin-top instead of top does fix this but the problem with that is that I have a jQuery slide animation when the sub navigation comes out and it doesn't look nice when I use margin-top since it comes out further up than it is. Here is a picture of the difference:

http://jsfiddle.net/eAqev/ <-- JS Fiddle

[image: The difference between Internet Explorer and Google Chrome]

HTML:

```
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><h1>01. About</h1><h2>Learn about us</h2></li>
            <li class="button"><h1>02. Products</h1><h2>View our selection of products</h2>
                <ul class="scrollDown">
                    <li><p>Kitchen Worktops</p></li>
                    <li><p>Upstands/Splashbacks</p></li>
                    <li><p>Gables/ Panels</p></li>
                    <li><p>Glass</p></li>
                    <li><p>High Gloss</p></li>
                    <li><p>Bathroom Tops</p></li>
                    <li><p>Sinks/ Taps</p></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><h1>03. Contact</h1><h2>Contact us!</h2></li>
            <li><h1>04. Gallery</h1><h2>View photos of us</h2></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#navigation ul {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

#navigation ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 10px;
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;
}

#navigation ul li:hover {
    border-bottom: 6px solid #eee;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#navigation ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1500;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style:none;
    background: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    top: 60px;
    opacity:0.95;
    filter:alpha(opacity=95);
    -moz-opacity:0.95;
}
```

Comment: What about a fiddle? What browsers works and what browsers doesn't work?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eAqev/ and Internet Explorer + firefox seem to be the same and Chrome is different. Not sure about others ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/eAqev/1/)***

Hi now define your **ID** `#navigation ul` `display:inline-block;` than adjects your  **id** `#navigation ul ul` in `top`

**As like this**

```
    #navigation ul {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
 #navigation ul ul {
        top:48px;
    }
```

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/eAqev/1/)**

Comment: This has worked! Thanks very much Rohit. Why does this affect it may I ask?

Comment: @LukeTurnbull now more about inline or inline-block go to this site http://dustwell.com/div-span-inline-block.html

Answer (score 5):

You made everything clear Just add the below codes.It will fix your problem

```
    #navigation ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1500;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    list-style:none;
    background: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    top: 60px;
    opacity:0.95;
    filter:alpha(opacity=95);
    -moz-opacity:0.95;
     }  


      #navigation ul {
      display: inline;
      z-index:10;
       position: relative;
        }
```

Most probably IE7 will have a buggy environment. This will work fine with IE8+.

Comment: I have whacked this in but it is still different on the browsers ! ~ Not sure what is wrong with it to be honest

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers have different default margin & padding on ul/li elements.
Have you tried resetting these all to 0?

```
#navigation ul, #navigation li {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: They've all be reset at the start with a html reset

Answer (score 0):

Might be you should try [css-reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)? Just put it at beginning of your css
But it may mess layout so you will need to set some values by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
    #navigation ul li {float: left;
 width: 200px;
line-height:17px;
margin: 10px;
list-style: none;
border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;
}
```